# Check Array for Object with Same Key

Tags: php, arrays, object

I'm creating an array of objects (or trying to) that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-28
    )

[5] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-28
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-29
    )

[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-30
    )

[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-30
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-09-30
    )

)
```

The trouble that I'm having is that I need can't work out how to check if an object with `date->$date` already exists.

I need an array of `'days'` that I can then go on to add workshops to the corresponding days, not to a new object each time.

Can anyone make a suggestion?

- - - EDIT

To put this in context, I'm iterating through a bunch of wordpress posts (of type 'workshop' in this case) which all have a piece of date meta. On my way through the loop I want to

- Get the date(day)
- Check if that date exists in the array
- If not, add the date to the array
- Then add the workshop object to that date array

What I should therefor end up with is an array containing three or four unique dates, each with an array of workshop objects.

```
Array( 
  Date 1( 
    Workshop( 
      Title, etc 
    ),
    Workshop()
   )
  Date 2( 
    Workshop(
      Title, etc
    )
    Workshop()
  )
)
```

My apologies, I'm sure my structure is off - this is a little advanced for me. Thanks for looking.

Comment: What you need is unclear. please explain more.

Comment: I've edited the question for context @masterFly.

Comment: maybe will be easier to work with the input as array, try decoding it `json_decode($jsonstring, true);`  and you will get an associative array.

Comment: So basically what you want to do is GROUP your objects (which are in the 1st array) from the date. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like this. You can have a function to group your result.

```
function groupWorkShopsByDate($first_array){
    $result_arr = array();
    foreach( $first_array as $workShop ){
        $result_arr[ $workShop->date ][] = $workShop;
    }
    return $result_arr;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes! That works like a charm. Thanks for you time @masterFly.

Comment: could you help me out a little further with sorting the array? I've managed to sort the dates into order with 'ksort()' but I need to go further and sort the workshops within each date and am stuck.

Comment: Basically you have to decide on what information you are going to sort workshops. then put is as the key of the array.

`$result_arr[ $workShop->date ][ <workshop sort key> ] = $workShop;`

then you can ksort them as you already did!